# How to search #unkown # in a string in dataframe in python

Tags: python, string

I have some rows in dataframe where one column has #Employer Unkown#, # Radar #. How can i find these in dataframe using python dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

matcher=re.compile(r'^#*#')
matches = [x for x in df['column'] if matcher.match(x)]
```